# Error on Colon When Using fstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use fstream and fout in C++ to export text to a file. It was about done, but when I tried to run it, it gives me errors:

```
1>c:\users\student\desktop\jackc     c++\pluginmaker\pluginmaker\pluginmaker.cpp(100): warning C4129: ':' : unrecognized character escape sequence
```

How do I fix this?

**Edited by moderator to add:**

This is the code, the last line is the one throwing the error:

```
ofstream fout; 
fout.open("plugin.txt");
fout<<"description\: " << plugindesc << "\n";
```

Comment: The code might be a good thing to show. Did you by chance use `\:` instead of `\\:`, though? Anything after a backslash becomes an escape code, so if you have valid ones in there, it's not going to work either. All backslashes in the strings should be doubled up. An example of one that could cause confusion is `\new directory\new file` instead of `\\new directory\\new file`, since `\n` is a newline character.

Comment: That's a compile-time error, show us pluginmaker.cpp (line 100).

Comment: We cannot figure out your problem without code. Please post it or we will be forced to close this question.

Comment: @egrunin - fout<<"description\: " << plugindesc << "\n";

Comment: @0A0D it's pretty clear, there's an error with the colon

Comment: Also, above the code that I showed to @egrunin, there is ofstream fout; fout.open("plugin.txt"); (on separate lines)

Comment: @JackCook, Your code explicitly says `\:`, not `\\:`.

Comment: @chris I need the colon to display, not the backslash

Comment: Whatever code you have needs to be in the question in the form of a minimal example that exhibits the problem, not in the comments.

Comment: @0A0D chris seems to understand

Comment: @JackCook: We are here to help, if you utilize the site properly, you'll get actual answers.

Comment: @KeybordPiano459, A colon does not require being an escape character. Omitting the backslash(es) before it, so it's like any other normal character, will display just a colon.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
fout<<"description\: " << plugindesc << "\n";
```

To this:

```
fout<<"description: " << plugindesc << "\n";
```

As @chris was trying to say: When the compiler sees the `\` inside the quoted string, it combines it with the next character, and assumes that the two together have a special meaning. For example, `\x` means *a hex number begins here*.

In your case, `\:` has *no* special meaning, so the compilers says *you've made a mistake*.